# How to get rid of these strange formattings in Webstorm

Tags: webstorm

using Webstorm in some files I have the following strange formattings (marked with red). How can I get rid of this kind of formattings? For what is it for?

[image]

Thanks & Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have some language injected into you HTML. Did you set up any custom language injections in Settings/language Injections? Also, please hit Alt+Enter inside these fragments - do you see 'Un-inject language' action in the dropdown?